# Wicket TagTester without providing attributes

Tags: java, html, unit-testing, junit, wicket

I have a component, which is a dataview of a table, whose markup looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td wicket:id="dateTime">Date/Time</td>
        <td wicket:id="direction">Direction</td>          
        <td wicket:id="ring">Ring</td>
        <td wicket:id="wait">Wait</td>
        <td wicket:id="talk">Talk</td>
        <td wicket:id="duration">Duration</td>
        <td wicket:id="answer">Answer</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr wicket:id="callList">
        <td wicket:id="dateTime">Date/Time</td>
        <td wicket:id="direction">Direction</td>
        <td wicket:id="ring">Ring</td>
        <td wicket:id="wait">Wait</td>
        <td wicket:id="talk">Talk</td>
        <td wicket:id="duration">Duration</td>
        <td wicket:id="answer">Answered</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I made some of the columns variable via controlling the visibility, so that the rendered result would not include them. I did this via a `DataView` instead of a `DataTable` because this keeps more control over the html in the html file, rather than code, which is the way I prefer it.

The problem arises is when I try to test the visibility. I feel like getting each of the components and testing for its visibility is a bit invasive for a unit test and would like to simply test the number of cells rendered in a row and see if it matches the number I expect (for a start).

I came across the [`TagTester`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/TagTester.html) and it seemed like a good solution to what I was trying to do.

However, TagTester seems to identify the tags via an attribute and its value and none of my cells have any common attributes by which they could be identified. Is it possible to create a TagTester only knowing what the tag is? Or am I wrong in how I'm thinking about unit testing such a component in general?

Answer (score 0):

`TagTester` has an *open tag*, a *close tag* and a *parser*. So when you create a TagTester for your example you will have : *open tag* = `<table>` and *close tag*= `</table>`. Currently TagTester allow you to :

1. `hasChildTag(String tagName)` : for searching tag by name,
2. `getChild(String attribute, String value)` : for getting the first `TagTester` child with attribute equals to value.

If you want to get a `Tag` inside your markup you can do it by searching your self inside the markup `myTagTester.getMarkup()` that returns a `String`.

Comment: That's the problem; how do I **create** a tag tester by only knowing the tag? The static methods on TagTester do not provide such functionality; they require you to know an attribute and it's value for that.

Comment: I haven't started using it yet, this was going to be my first go. I expected that the only ways to build it [are the static methods in the TagTester javadoc](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/TagTester.html#createTagByAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: You can implement your own TagFinder. Could you tell me how do you build your TagTester ? with BaseWicketTester ? and why you want searching by Tags ? could you give me an example of use ?

Comment: See my original question for why I need to get TagTesters by tags. I haven't built any TagTesters yet, I was looking for a way to build them without knowing the attributes, which is how the TagTester static methods let you do it. Also, the ways to build the TagTester from the WicketTester seem to require the wicket ID, which, as you can see in the question, differs for all the tags I want to get.

Comment: So with the static method `WicketTester.getTagsByWicketId(WicketTester tester, String wicketId)` it returns an `List<TagTester>` and you need just to iterate and do `tagTester.getName()`

Comment: Could you give amend the answer and give an example? That would be really helpful.